# Recuperar información de XML con XSLT en cursiva

Tags: xslt

Quiero recuperar los nombres propios de un XML a través de XSLT, pero con la condición de que **cuanto haya `ex` se imprima el texto en cursiva**.

Este es el XML que tengo:

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-model href="http://www.tei-c.org/release/xml/tei/custom/schema/relaxng/tei_all.rng" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://www.tei-c.org/release/xml/tei/custom/schema/relaxng/tei_all.rng" type="application/xml"
    schematypens="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="textocorto.xsl"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <teiHeader>
        <fileDesc>
            <titleStmt>
                <title>Title</title>
            </titleStmt>
            <publicationStmt>
                <p>Publication Information</p>
            </publicationStmt>
            <sourceDesc>
                <p>Information about the source</p>
            </sourceDesc>
        </fileDesc>
    </teiHeader>
    <text>
        <body>
            <pb n="001r"/>
            <div1 type="book" n="01">
                
                <div2 type="chapter" n="000">
                    <cb n="a"/>
                    <head> Capítulo 1 </head>
                    <ab> Este es el texto del capítulo 1 de la columna A del folio 1r y le pongo dos
                        nombrecitos <name>Don alfo<ex>ns</ex>so</name> y otro nombrecillo para no perdernos doña
                        <name>beatriz</name>
                    </ab>
                </div2>
                <div2>
                    <cb n="b"/>
                    <head>Capítulo II </head>
                    
                    <ab>Este es el texto del capítulo II, que se encuentra en la columba B del folio 1r.
                        Y vamos a poner unos nombres: don <name>al<ex>fon</ex>so</name>, doña <name>Urraca</name>
                    </ab>
                </div2>
                <pb n="001v"/>
                <div2>
                    <head>Capítulo III</head>
                    <ab> Este es el texto del capítulo 3. Vamos a poner tres nombres:
                        <name>Fer<ex>nan</ex>do</name>, <name>Le<ex>tic</ex>ia</name> e <name>I<ex>s</ex>a</name>
                    </ab>
                </div2>
                            </div1>
        </body>
    </text>
</TEI>

Y esta es la hoja de estilos XSL
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html lang="es">
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
                
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Nombres propios</h1>
                <xsl:for-each select="tei:TEI//tei:name">
                    <p/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/tei:TEI/tei:text/tei:body/tei:pb"/>,
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/tei:TEI/tei:text/tei:body/tei:div1/tei:div2/tei:cb"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/tei:TEI/tei:text/tei:body/tei:div1/tei:div2"/>
                    
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
            
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="/tei:TEI/tei:text/tei:body/tei:pb">
        <xsl:for-each select="/tei:TEI/tei:text/tei:body/tei:div1/tei:div2/tei:ab/tei:name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@n"/>: <xsl:value-of
            select="/tei:TEI/tei:text/tei:body/tei:div1/tei:div2/tei:ab/tei:name"/>
        
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/tei:TEI/tei:text/tei:body/tei:div1/tei:div2/tei:cb">
        <xsl:for-each select="/tei:TEI/tei:text/tei:body/tei:div1/tei:div2/tei:ab/tei:name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@n"/>
        
        
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/tei:TEI/tei:text/tei:body/tei:div1/tei:div2">
        <xsl:for-each select="/tei:TEI/tei:text//tei:div1/tei:div2/tei:ab/tei:name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@n"/>
    </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```